# imageJ java : variable defined in one macro cannot be called in a second macro?

Tags: java, variables, macros, iteration, imagej

I am using imageJ which i think is basically Java. In one macro I define a variable "i" as 0 and I am trying to call i in another macro and then increase it by one each time i run that second macro:

```
macro "number1[1]"{
i=0;
}

macro "number2[2]"{
some function using i;
i++;
}
```

The goal is to set i as zero, then start using macro number2 (performing some function using the variable i) and increasing each time macro number2 is run (some undetermined number of times) until i decide to reset i to 0 using macro number1 again (at some undetermined ahead of time point...otherwise I would work this into a for loop).

I run macro number1 and then when i try to run macro number2.. "i" is not recognized as a variable. What's up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `i` variable outside of the macros:

```
var i = 0;

macro "Reset count [1]" {
  i = 0;
}

macro "Increment count [2]" {
  i++;
}
```

See the documentation on [Macro Sets](http://imagej.net/developer/macro/macros.html#sets) for details.

P.S. The ImageJ macro language is not Java. It is more like Javascript actually, but with many more limitations. Consider using one of the [supported scripting languages](http://imagej.net/Scripting) instead to gain access to the complete Java API of ImageJ and its plugins.